# PaintComponent перерисовать

Tags: java

Здравствуйте.

есть JFrame и я на нем рисую какие то фигуры через paintComponent

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        g.drawRect(50, 50, 50, 50);
        g.drawOval(60, 60, 60, 60);

        //repaint();
        //g.drawOval(10, 10, 10, 10); - никакого эффекта
}
```

и все отлично работает. Но в один момент, я хочу все стереть и нарисовать вместо этого, к примеру, другую фигуру. Как я могу это реализовать. Есть метод repaint(), но я не уверен подойдет ли он к данному случаю, бо мне не удается им воспользоваться, вероятно я с ним что то делаю не так

Comment: Помогло это, но правильный ли это подход?

    repaint();
    super.paintComponent(g);